# Do the choices on Game of Thrones Telltale games always lead to the same result?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Hey Guys I was wondering if all choices always lead to the same results in GoT Telltale Games.
For example Whatever choice you have chosen Lord Ethan is always killed by Ramsey Snow.
On all choices Lord Forrester's squire always kills a Whitehill/Boston(I didn't really notice) soldier and gets sent to the wall. Does this game have any major changes throughout the Story or are there just the same results all over the game? I don't want to waste my time with downloading more episodes because I live in a country with very high internet price. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having played a lot of telltale games (but not the GOT one), decisions will pretty much always end up at the same point later down the line.

Example: Me and a friend played through a season of TWD simultaneously. I end up saving some girl, he doesnt (and she dies).

For me, she didn't contribute much after that, and died a chapter later.

So I'd say, yes, in some minor ways some things might change (a few choices could block you making a choice later) but in the broad strokes, the story will have the same beats. You will pretty much always end up to the same big story moment, any way you try to play.